# Mac OS 10.14.4 installation stuck in Mac mini late 2014

Tags: macos, installation, macos-mojave, dmg

I am using Mac mini mid 2014 model.I tried installing Mac OS 10.14.4 using dmg .But installation is stuck halfway.I have attached the screenshot.Please help me with this.[image]

Comment: My best guess is that you are running an older macOS version and your SSD is formatted as HFS+ when Mojave needs to be installed on an APFS volume. You might need a 10.14.4 combo updater instead of a 10.14.4 standalone updater so that the updater can reformat your disk to APFS.

Comment: @eckenrod Tried installing 10.14.4 combo updater, but still facing the same issue.